# frequent time out errors on ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, apache

when I was developing my website I was testing it as localhost, but now as it is almost complete I am using my local ip address and I find I am getting time out errors for about 30% of my ajax calls. and sometimes 'failed to load resource errors'. I don't know why this is happening so frequently. I am using an apache 2.4.9 web server. In localhost mode It always worked perfectly. The error message in the console is: `GET http://109.156.x.xx/check_session.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.
the timeout is set at 30 seconds (which should be plenty);

The ajax code for this is:

```
    $.get('/check_session.php',function(data){
      if(data == "lo"){
        //do something
      }else{
        //do something else
   }
});
```

is there any way to prevent these errors? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Add `set_time_limit(0)` at the start of your php file after the php start tag (